# Azure Search - Azure Portal - Please allow portal origin in your index

Tags: azure, search

I have been searching in my index created remotely (Umbraco) via the Azure portal using Azure Search.

This morning i get the error telling me to allow portal origin in my index.

I dont understand why i was able to search yesterday and today its telling me i cannot.

I am not able to change the settings, i might be able to re create the index :/

Comment: for us the issue fixed itself :) so i guess it was some kind of bug on microsofts end

Answer (score 1):

today I had the same case and it is enough to the 'CORS' tab in the 'Allowed origins' field 'https://portal.azure.com'